# What is exactly hostname for sending Microsoft Exchange email with mailcore

Tags: mailcore2

I can not send MS Exchange email with mailcore.
It always returns an error "A stable connection to the server could not be established".
Here is my code

```
    smtpSession.hostname = @"smtp.outlook.office365.co.uk";
    smtpSession.username = [currentUser objectForKey:@"email_account"];
    smtpSession.password = [currentUser objectForKey:@"email_password"];
    smtpSession.port = 25;
    smtpSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionTypeClear;
```

I think it because of the hostname.
Could anybody tell me what is exactly hostname of MS Exchange in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out answer here

```
smtpSession.hostname = @"smtp.office365.com";
    smtpSession.username = [currentUser objectForKey:@"email_account"];
    smtpSession.password = [currentUser objectForKey:@"email_password"];
    smtpSession.port = 25;
    smtpSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionTypeStartTLS;
```

Comment: Would you mind posting a complete example sending a message using mailcore?

Answer (score 0):

For future reference for others here's a complete example using MailCore2 added using CocoaPods

```
#import <MailCore/MailCore.h>

MCOSMTPSession *smtpSession = [[MCOSMTPSession alloc] init];
smtpSession.hostname = @"smtp.outlook.office365.com";
smtpSession.username = @"user@domain.com";
smtpSession.password = @"NotMyPass";
smtpSession.port = 587;
smtpSession.connectionType = MCOConnectionTypeStartTLS;

MCOMessageBuilder * builder = [[MCOMessageBuilder alloc] init];
[[builder header] setFrom:[MCOAddress addressWithDisplayName:@"Me" mailbox:@"user@domain.com"]];
[[builder header] setTo:@[[MCOAddress addressWithDisplayName:@"To you" mailbox:@"user@domain.com"]]];
[[builder header] setSubject:@"Mailcore test"];
[builder setTextBody:@"Message received"];
NSData * rfc822Data = [builder data];

MCOSMTPSendOperation *sendOperation = [smtpSession sendOperationWithData:rfc822Data];
[sendOperation start:^(NSError *error) {
    if(error) {
        NSLog(@"Error sending email:%@", error);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Successfully sent email!");
    }
}];
```